# Creating a post with hidden inputs to Azure ACS to avoid redirect to login page

Tags: azure, acs, federated-identity

I have successfully linked ACS to ADFS and our website user's authenticate against ADFS without issue.
I also have legacy sites that authenticate directly against AD via custom code and IAG.

We would like the users of the legacy site, once authenticated, to bypass having to login again to enter our new sites. Removing IAG is not an option at this moment.

I have the ability to add additional pages to the legacy site and I can create addition IP's in ACS. My attempt so far has been to create a self signed cert, generate a federatedmetdata.xml based on that cert file and import that into ACS. That went well. Then I wanted to try and create the WSResponse  and claims for the WSignin1.0 request and post that to ACS using the same cert I used to create the metadata file. That action would occur from the legacy site. That has not went so well as I usually receive a HTTP error code of 500 with the "ACS20001: An error occurred while processing a WS-Federation sign-in response" from ACS.
Basically I would like to know if what i am doing is feasible? , or perhaps there is a better way given the constraint of IAG, or if I am close and should continue down the path I am on.

Comment: I know nothing about IAG but this link appears to mention something about getting IAG to work with SSO. Is it helpful? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd278028.aspx

Comment: I am still reading it but that appears more towards SSO with IAG and I am trying to hook it up to ACS. I noticed another link from there taht may have got me thinking about IAG and ADFS and looking there as well. I really think I should be able to do this as I am just acting like a small STS without true endpoints. That may be a flaw though.